# PLSQL Procedure needs to return single value at a time, if there are more than one records in table

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create procedure that should return single value at a time. Actually, I already did but there is one challenge that I am facing.

Suppose, I am passing 3 inputs to the procedure and as per those input procedure will return single output. But the table I am referring consist of more that one result for that particular query and my procedure is returning multiplestate exception to me.

Can anyone please help me in this case. Below is the procedure I am using.

```
PROCEDURE p_regidexport(countryid IN varchar2, cropid IN varchar2, productid IN VARCHAR2, pregid out varchar2)
IS
fnc       VARCHAR2(30) := 'P_REGIDEXPORT';
query     VARCHAR2(10000);
regid varchar2(20);


BEGIN
        begin
          select nvl(REG_ID,'0') into regid from Registration 
          where 
          LOC_ID =(select loc_id from location where Country = countryid ) AND 
          CROP_ID = (select crop_id from crop where CROP_NM =  cropid)AND 
          REG_NAME = productid ;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line('No record ');  --- or regid  ='0';  
        end;
        pregid := regid;
        --sub_log('P_REGIDEXPORT:'||pregid);
        dbms_output.put_line(pregid);
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No record present' || ' - ' || sqlerrm);      
    END P_REGIDEXPORT;
```

Comment: If the result of that query has more than one row, which one is the correct row according to you?

Comment: Both are correct, but it should pickup first and give the result and similarly do it for second record.

Comment: @G.Chahar So for each input multiple results are coming and you just need the first one, Corrct?

Comment: But how do we decide which row is first?

Comment: You can make your out variable a `ref cursor`  and just open cursor instead of performing `into regid` . However, you may need to handle `no data exception` in calling program where you fetch it.  If you need only a single value to be passed, then there should be a  reason to restrict the number of rows to 1 , which you have not mentioned anything.

Comment: @XING , it is not like I only need first result. Suppose there are three records coming in a table for any select query and there is only unique ID related with each record. SO I want unique ID for all three records but ne at a time.

Comment: You should use the `ref cursor` approach suggested by @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 0):

Chahar, For your requirement you can use pipeline function. In this you can call call the function as if you call the table. Please find the sample code below which will help you understanding the concept.

Sample Code as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE TEST_PIPELINE AS 

type return_varchar is table of varchar2(4000);

  /* TODO enter package declarations (types, exceptions, methods etc) here */ 

FUNCTION row_generator return return_varchar PIPELINED ;
END TEST_PIPELINE;


CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY TEST_PIPELINE AS

  FUNCTION row_generator return return_varchar PIPELINED  AS
  BEGIN
    -- TODO: Implementation required for FUNCTION TEST_PIPELINE.row_generator
   for i in  (select col1 from(
select 1 as col1 from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual)) loop
    pipe row(i.col1);
end loop;



  END row_generator;

END TEST_PIPELINE;
```

Calling the pipeline function:

```
select * from table(TEST_PIPELINE.row_generator);
```

I have modified your code, please have a look:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE regdexport AS 

type return_varchar is table of varchar2(4000);


FUNCTION p_regidexport(countryid IN varchar2, cropid IN varchar2, productid IN VARCHAR2, pregid out varchar2) return return_varchar PIPELINED ;
END regdexport;


CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY regdexport AS
FUNCTION p_regidexport(countryid IN varchar2, cropid IN varchar2, productid IN VARCHAR2, pregid out varchar2) return return_varchar
IS
fnc       VARCHAR2(30) := 'P_REGIDEXPORT';
query     VARCHAR2(10000);
regid varchar2(20);


BEGIN
        begin
          for  i in (select nvl(REG_ID,'0') into regid from Registration 
          where 
          LOC_ID =(select loc_id from location where Country = countryid ) AND 
          CROP_ID = (select crop_id from crop where CROP_NM =  cropid)AND 
          REG_NAME = productid) 
          loop
                pipe row(i.regid);
          end loop;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line('No record ');  --- or regid  ='0';  
        end;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No record present' || ' - ' || sqlerrm);      
    END P_REGIDEXPORT;
```

Calling the function:

```
select * from table(regdexport.p_regidexport(par1,par2,par3));
```

Hope this helps.